# Proxy - handler.ownKeys() - nested object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

How can I handle all traps for ownKeys in a nested object?

I only know how to handle one level deep object:

```
function wrap(obj, fn) {
  var handler = {
    ownKeys(target) {
      fn(target)
      return target
    }
  }
  return new Proxy(obj, handler)
}

var origObj = {
  a: {
    b: {
     c: 0
    }
  }
}

var wrappedObj = wrap(origObj, console.log)

Object.keys(wrappedObj) // => actual = expected: { a: { b: { c: 0 } } }
Object.keys(wrappedObj.a) // => actual: not working, expected: { b: { c: 0 } }
Object.keys(wrappedObj.a.b) // => actual: not working, expected: { c: 0 }
```

**edit 1:**

If I try to wrap each inner object (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45978003/7027774)) then it logs all steps not just the last one. By "all steps" I mean the inner process of the proxy which goes through the whole nested object so it fires `fn(target)` multiple times but I want to fire it only once.

[image: Output in the console]

**edit 2:**

So it looks that the problem is with the node environmnent (node version 8.1.4) where `proxy` looks broken. In the chrome console is everything ok.

Comment: Only `origObj` is proxied, the inner objects are not.

Comment: Yes, I know that's why I asked how can I do that for nested object (sry for my english).

Comment: If you don't want to create proxies recursively, you need to traverse the `target` inside the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a proxy for every single of the objects:

```
var wrappedObj = wrap({
  a: wrap({
    b: wrap({
     c: 0
    }, console.log)
  }, console.log)
}, console.log)
```

If you don't want to do that explicitly, you can of course also traverse the object using recursion to do the wrapping programmatically, or you do create the proxies dynamically on every property access via the `get` trap.

Comment: This doesn't work because it logs all steps not just the last one.

Comment: @MatejMazur What do you mean by "just the last one"? I thought you wanted each of the three `Object.keys` calls to trigger the log.

Comment: I've updated my question with the screenshot of the console where it's visible the output.

Comment: @MatejMazur Ah, I see now. That seems to be a problem with your console - the `console.log` itself does enumerate the contents of the logged object, triggering its trap again. Try in another environment or with a different callback function. (It shows as expected in Chrome devtools for example)

Comment: I see! Interesting.. thanks for the clarification! :)